# Is the order of elements in an array returned by getElementsByClassName/Id consistent?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm wondering if the order of elements returned in the arrays of `getElementsByclassName()` and it's ilk (e.g. `getElementById()`) are consistent/guaranteed or is it engine dependent? The basic test I performed in the javascript developers console seems to indicate that it is and ordered from top down

Comment: You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById for browser compatibility

Comment: @Huangism I already did, but it doesn't mention whether the contents of the array or it's order is guaranteed. Which is what I wish to know

Comment: It will grab the elements based on the html order. So like you said top to bottom, assuming no elements are added or removed after the collecting process

Comment: Well you kinda answered your own question 
`The basic test I performed in the javascript developers console seems to indicate that it is and ordered from top down`

Comment: @Troy Yes I did. I tested this with the latest browsers at the time but I couldn't be sure about older browsers or whether this was governed by a standard or a recent compliance by the browsers at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like based on the W3 site, it would be safe to assume consistent order

"Let classes be the result of running the ordered set parser on classNames."

http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-dom-20150428/#concept-getelementsbyclassname
http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-dom-20150428/#concept-ordered-set-parser

EDIT:

The above was only about 1/2 the answer as @mccc pointed out. When searching for multiple classes, order does not matter inside the arguments, however the returned results are guarneteed to be in order. This is because collections retunred are requried to be HtmlCollections, and the spec defines HtmlCollections as being in Tree Order. This, by definition, means that the elements will be returned top down.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-dom-20150428/#concept-tree-order

@mcc also pointed another helpful link to help drive the point home:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-dom-20150428/#concept-collection

So in short, elements returned by `getElementsByClassName()` will be in top down order.

Comment: That is talking about _classes_, though, and it means that classnames (the argument to the call) are parsed as an ordered list, which itself means that the arguments order does not matter, as shown in [this example](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#example-48a90db5). The question, unfortunately, stands.

Comment: Yes the arguments order doesn't seem to matter, but if you dig into HtmlCollections it says that it is returning in Tree Order. Does that not guarantee ordering across browsers? http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-dom-20150428/#concept-tree-order

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right: it says so in the [collections concepts](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-dom-20150428/#concept-collection)! Still, not what you were talking about in your answer :) Might consider editing that..

Comment: I agree :) I will update it when I'm at my computer again. Thanks for the push to dig a bit further!